# code in mathematica for the game of guessing

Tags: webmathematica, game

Can we write code in Mathematica for the game where the user guesses an integer between 1-99 produced by the computer? If you have any ideas, I would be glad if you could help. I tried this:

```
number = RandomInteger[{1, 99}]; 
While[guess =!= number, guess = Input["Guess my number"]]; 
Print["Well guessed!"]
```

Comment: You could start your program by saving this into a variable: `RandomInteger[{1, 99}]`

Comment: THANKS. I tried this but the system stays running. For example, I can find between 1-10 immediately, but as the range gets bigger, 1-100, the more I get errors from the system. Can we get this before?

Comment: Please show the code you are running -- that will help us to help you.

Comment: number = RandomInteger[{1, 99}];
While[guess =!= number, guess = Input["Guess my number"]];
Print["Well guessed!"]

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a minimal solution to get you started.

```
DynamicModule[{n, guess = 0}, 
    {
     InputField[Dynamic[guess], Number], 
     Dynamic[If[n == guess, "You won", "Try again"]],
     Dynamic[n] (* for debugging *)
    }, 
 Initialization :> (n = RandomInteger[{1, 99}])]
```

Type a number, press tab, see if you win.